# Merge 2 audio streams and a video stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to merge 2 audio files and a video file. I also want the audio to run synchronously. I am trying to execute `ffmpeg -i 4.mkv -i 12.mp3 -i 13.mp3 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 muxed.mkv`. As a result, I get a video with only one audio file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the **complete** log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `-map` attribute which is used to replace audio tracks, that’s why you are getting just one audio clip.

This might help you:-

`ffmpeg -i 4.mkv -i 12.mp3 -i 13.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac muxed.mkv`

Comment: Because you omitted `-map` ffmpeg will use the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior. This will only select one stream per stream type.